# How to get the text of item from spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

i am trying to fetch the item text from my spinner view by matching a name but not able to do yet.Here is the code i have used :

```
for(int i=0;i<calendar_spinner.getAdapter().getCount();i++) {
           String s= calendar_spinner.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
           System.out.println("Calendars are"+s);
           if(calendar_Name.equals(s))
         { 
          System.out.println("Calendar setted");
          calendar_spinner.setSelection(i); 
          break;
         }
}
```

and i am getting the output for s as com.android.calendermodel.MyCalendarsModel@405872a0 Not exactly the name, something different...

Answer (score 6):

Check this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for a solution to a very similar problem:

For ArrayAdapter you can do:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
int i = adapter.getPosition("blue");
s.setSelection(i);
```

For custom adapter you can do:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
for(i=0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
  if("blue".equals(adapter.getItem(i).toString())){
    s.setSelection(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Got this info from:
http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/23-android-spinner-tips?start=1

Answer (score 2):

That's not a proper way to do it. You should be using **setOnItemSelectedListener** of the Spinner. If you insists to do it your way, you can override **toString** method of your object to only return the text you wanted.

Comment: Hi dear, I am not trying to capture the text onSelecteditem event. Let me make you clear first. I have a spinner in my insertion form where i am choosing the item and inserting it into database. Then i am also having a spinner in my update form, My problem is how to set the Item inserted previously from insert form as default value for update spinner... For that purpose i am trying to fetch all item text showing by my spinner, So that i can match them with my database value and then set the default one...

Comment: In that case simply overriding toString can solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override getItem method to return a string only, when Declaring adapter. by following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1, arr)
{
     public Object getItem(int position)
     {
        return arr[position];
     }
};
```

Comment: Hi dear, I am not trying to capture the text onSelecteditem event. Let me make you clear first. I have a spinner in my insertion form where i am choosing the item and inserting it into database. Then i am also having a spinner in my update form, My problem is how to set the Item inserted previously from insert form as default value for update spinner... For that purpose i am trying to fetch all item text showing by my spinner, So that i can match them with my database value and then set the default one.... And yes i am not using ArrayAdapter.. I am using Custom Adapter.

Comment: okay, so if you are declaring custom adapter then you can override getItem method as I did, and in loop call getItem method, it will return string and save it into db.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get the spinner choice name? That is simple, you don't need to call its adapter, it's just:

`String itemName = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`

If you want to perform an action(for example filter your calendar) only when the spinner choice is changed you can implement an `OnItemSelected` listener to your spinner.

Comment: Hi dear, I am not trying to capture the text onSelecteditem event. Let me make you clear first. I have a spinner in my insertion form where i am choosing the item and inserting it into database. Then i am also having a spinner in my update form, My problem is how to set the Item inserted previously from insert form as default value for update spinner... For that purpose i am trying to fetch all item text showing by my spinner, So that i can match them with my database value and then set the default one...